# Java 10 'var' will spawn a bug without full rebuild

Tags: java, var, rebuild, java-10

Please refer below example.

**==== before ====**

---- A.java ---

```
var userAccounts = userService.getUserAccounts();
```

--- B.java

```
class UserService {
public OldUserAccounts getUserAccounts();
}
```

**==== after ====**

---- A.java ---

```
var userAccounts = userService.getUserAccounts();
```

--- B.java

```
class UserService {
public NewUserAccounts getUserAccounts();
}
```

There is no change in the B.java source file although A.java changed.
the B.class file's information has the 'userAccounts' variable type is 'OldUserAccounts'
Aren't you?
if i apply modified source files to the real server.
'var' will spawn a bug ?

**Note :** *I know its a bad practice, even without var changes can be bytecode-incompatible. the idea of rebuilding the entire project is not good in my case.
cost is too much*

Any ides or workarounds ??

Comment: actually, the change seems to be in B.java

Comment: *Most programmers will only apply modified source files to the real server*: no. No one sane does that. Sane developers use their build tool to compile, assemble and test their code. The produced artifact (a jar file or a war file, often acompanied with several other files (config, etc.)) are then uploaded and replace the previous install. Source files are not needed on the server.

Comment: *"the idea of rebuilding the entire project is not good in my case. cost is too much"* How can the "cost" be too much? How long does a full build take? If your project is so large that build takes more than a few minutes, then you should be doing daily builds on a build server. Heck, you should probably be doing that anyway, regardless of build time. And a really large project should be split into modules *(not necessarily Java 9 modules)*. Your build is **automated**, right?

Comment: If you have any problems with `var` in a very specific case, there *is* a workaround. Declare the type in that case.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `var`.  If you'd written `A` with a manifest type (`OldUserAccounts u = service.getUserAccounts()`), it would break in exactly the same way.  The problem is you made a binary-incompatible change.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> There is no change in the B.java source file although A.java changed.

You mean there's no change in `A.java` even though `B.java` changed.

Yes, if you change `B.java`, you must recompile `A.java`, which depends on it. `var` doesn't change anything in this regard, you needed to do that anyway. The only difference is that the source code in `A.java` doesn't change if you use `var`, and does if you don't. It needs recompiling **regardless**.

> Most programmers will only apply modified source files to the real server.

Citation needed.

Most programmers on non-toy projects use a proper build tool. Using a proper build tool will ensure you recompile and redeploy as necessary. If you're picking-and-choosing what you recompile and redeploy, and not always recompiling classes when their dependencies change, you will indeed have a problem as of Java 10 — and you already have a problem in Java 9 and earlier. You **will** make an incompatible change to `B.java`, fail to recognize you need to modify and rebuild `A.java`, and hit a runtime incompatibility.

`var` isn't the problem in the scenario you describe. The project tooling is.

But `var` is entirely optional. If you think it will cause trouble on your project, don't use it.

Comment: Fun fact: the type of local variables is mostly irrelevant to the execution, so it is indeed irrelevant whether `var` has been used or not. It’s already the invocation instruction pointing to `OldUserAccounts getUserAccounts()` in `UserService` that breaks when the return type changes.